# Filtering by author and counting all numbers im txt file - Linux terminal, bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I need help with two hings

1)the file.txt has the format of a list of films
, in which they are authors in different lines, year of publication, title, e.g.

```
author1
year1
title1
author2
year2
title2
author3
year3
title3
author4
year4
title4
```

I need to show only book titles whose author is "Joanne Rowling"

2)
one.txt contains numbers and letters for example like:

```
dada4dawdaw54 232dawdawdaw 53 34dadasd
77dkwkdw
65 23 laka 23
```

I need to sum all of them and receive score - here it should 561

I tried something like that:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)s+=$i}END{print s}' plik2.txt
```

but it doesn't make sense

Comment: For #1 maybe `grep -A 3 "Joanne Rowling" `. If you want to get the title only, `awk` is your friend with record number modulo 3 (and in any case, awk *is* your friend).

Comment: For #2, `| tr -d "[a-z]"` should help you too (I can't test anything right now).

Comment: You need to present your attempt for (1). You need to be consistent, either `one.txt` or `plik2.txt` is the name of your file in (2). You also need to explain `but it doesn't make sense`, which is neither an error message nor the output of the program.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st question, the solution of okulkarni is great.

For the 2nd question, one solution is

```
sed 's/[^0-9]/ /g' one.txt | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+= $i} END { print sum}'
```

The `sed` command converts all non-numeric characters into spaces, while the `awk` command sums the numbers, line by line.

Answer (score -1):

For the first question, you just need to use `grep`. Specifically, you can do `grep -A 2 "Joanne Rowling" file.txt`. This will show all lines with "Joanne Rowling" and the two lines immediately after.

For the second question, you can also use `grep` by doing `grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | paste -sd+ | bc`. This will put a `+` between every number found by `grep` and then add them up using `bc`.